# Can Chrome extension or apps communicate with macbook touchbar?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, macbookpro-touch-bar

I was wondering if chrome extensions or chrome app, can they communicate with the new [macbook pro touchbar](https://developer.apple.com/macos/touch-bar/)?

I was thinking to bring in the same capabilities to touch bar (in the case of chrome) which are there in the safari. As in when you play a video on youtube safari and when you put it on full screen mode, touch bar shows nice video progress slider and volume and fullscreen controls...

Or if there is some other way if extension or apps cant solve it?

Comment: Related: [Has Apple released APIs for touch bar yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292937/has-apple-released-apis-for-touch-bar-yet)

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is no: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

You would need a **native application** that takes care of actually changing the Touch Bar contents and then communicate to it through an HTTP server, WebSocket server or [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/)

I don't expect the Touch Bar to ever be available directly via Chrome APIs, but one can hope.